# Intellij structural search for method invocation where class containing method is marked with specific annotation

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

Intellij structural search script to to find all method invocations where method source class is marked with @Internal annotation.
As for example bellow - script should return
**a.a();**

```
package com.interestingpackage.internal
import com.common.Internal;

@Internal
public class A {
    public void a() {}
}
```

```
package com.common

public @interface Internal {}
```

```
package com.my.service

public class B  {
    private A a;
    void d() {
        a.a();
    }
};
```

**Template**

```
$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$)
```

**Variables**

```
$MethodCall$

[script] = 
import com.intellij.psi.* 
__context__ instanceof PsiMethodCallExpression && 
__context__.resolveMethod() != null &&
java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("com\\.interestingpackage\\.(?!notfrompackage).+", __context__.resolveMethod().getContainingClass().getQualifiedName()) &&
com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.isAnnotated(__context__.resolveMethod().getContainingClass(),"com.common.Internal", true)
```

**Result**
Search doesn't return method call **a.a();** as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern works for me when I add a `[0,∞]` count modifier on `$parameter$`.

Comment: Yes, looks missing [0,∞] was the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

In your example "a" method does not accept any parameters, so it wound not match

```
$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$)
```

try using

```
$Instance$.$MethodCall$()
```

instead.